# Search component pointing to wrong SEF URLs in Joomla 3

Tags: joomla-3.x, sef, .htaccess-configuration, search

My search component is pointing to the wrong URLs. When the user clicks on them, they're redirected to the home page.

For example, the search returns:

http://cursos.portal-gestao.com/9-excel/introducao/158-lista-de-formulas-ingles-portugues

When the correct URL is:

http://cursos.portal-gestao.com/indice-do-curso-excel/9-excel/introducao/158-lista-de-formulas-ingles-portugues

This is just an example, there are other variations.

I'm trying to find a way to write the URLs with the article ID on them, something like:

http://cursos.portal-gestao.com/?Itemid=158-lista-de-formulas-ingles-portugues

And then using .htaccess to redirect all pages to the same structure.

But this URL isn't returning the correct page.

Is there any way to fix the search component or use the process above to solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best practice to avoid any unpredictable urls is to create "Articles - Category List" or "Articles - Category Blog" menu items for all your top level article categories. This way all your articles will inherit the url structure from these menu aliases.

1. Go to Menus->Add New Menu
2. Create a Menus say "Articles"
3. Go to that Menus
4. Add the menu item for each of the top level category

Comment: Interesting solution. What do you mean by 'top level category'? Those categories without parent?

Comment: Yes, those categories which are having parent as root.

Comment: Silly. But it worked!! Thank You!