# K2 SEF issues including Joomla Smart Search

Tags: joomla-3.x, k2, sef, smartsearch

I am having an issue with smart search and k2. If I search for a Joomla article then everything pulls the correct SEF URL. If I try to search for something that is a k2 item it loads correctly but wants to send it a non SEF page and also wants to load on the default menu item.

I tried using answer here: [Search component pointing to wrong SEF URLs in Joomla 3](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/10018/search-component-pointing-to-wrong-sef-urls-in-joomla-3)

That didn't work either.

Here is how I have it set up:

sitename.com/corporate/cg1/main/press-releases - this pulls in all the items

sitename.com/corporate/cg1/main/press-releases/item/421-article-alias-name - it appears that the "421" is the k2 item id.

sitename.com/421-article-alias-name - is how it appears in the smart search which forces it to load on the default menu item.

Any insights would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I can not replicate the issue.
Are you sure you have setup a proper Menu Items structure for your K2 items?

Also note that if you have another menu item for the same content items, this might take precedence over others. If for example your homepage menu item is also a K2 categories or something, then your articles might become available under that menu item.

Also make sure that the k2 items you think have a problem do actually belong to that category that you have created menu item for.

Finally this might be also related to 3rd party SEF extensions.